# Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected

Tags: iphone, ios4, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHttpRequest library in iphone and when i try to do a GET request on the below URL i get this message and the request fails, please anyone if he/she has encountered this problem or know a possible solution to it please let me know. Secondly if i paste the link in the browser it works perfectly fine.

[URL]

http://www.rugsale.com/iphone/app/?type=product_list&params=id%3D334&ver=1.0&key=kaoud

[ERROR]

Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSStringEncodingASCII. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.

Thx in advance

Regards

Syed Arsalan Pervez
www.saplogix.net

Comment: you need to put the code in the post,  where the call originates.

Comment: Some code will help us understand what's wrong with your calls

Answer (score 5):

This notably happens if you call `[asiHttpRequest getResponseString]` before a valid response has been returned and the request encoding has been set (i.e. couldn't connect to server).

The easiest way to workaround this warning is by editing the `ASIHTTPRequest` class, remove the `@synthesize responseEncoding` and adding a simple custom getter/setter so you can return the default encoding if the response encoding isn't set:

```
- (NSStringEncoding) responseEncoding
{
    return responseEncoding || self.defaultResponseEncoding;
}

- (void) setResponseEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)_responseEncoding
{
    responseEncoding = _responseEncoding;
}
```

There's also a more specific workaround for the `getResponseString` method, which I think is the only place that uses the encoding without checking for a value - since the encoding should be set for any non-zero length response:

```
- (NSString *)responseString
{
    NSData *data = [self responseData];
    if (!data) {
        return nil;
    }
    // --- INSERT THIS BLOCK ---
    // If the 'data' is present but empty, return a simple empty string
    if (data.length == 0) {
        return @"";
    }
    //assert(self.responseEncoding); // if you're into runtime asserts, uncomment this
    // --- END OF BLOCK TO INSERT ---
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:[self responseEncoding]] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: `self.responseEncoding = _responseEncoding;` -- sigh… infinite loop

Comment: `self.responseEncoding = ...` uses the property setter, `responseEncoding = ...` just sets the value of the ivar.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was timeout wasn't enough. So it returns an empty response. So it gives this error because you'r trying to do something with an empty response. I increased the time for it. So it solved my problem.`[request setTimeOutSeconds:200];`

Comment: For me also the same problem, thanks It solved my problem. I did not declared the request time out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this is just saying that the encoding was nil, when a value was expected.  Try doing a search for "encoding:nil" or "encoding:NULL" in your source code and replace it with a valid encoding, for example NSStringEncodingASCII...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that's cropped up in the 4.2 SDK.  I didn't see this until I updated my development environment myself.

All-Seeing Interactive will probably have to update the code to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

The error is where you are creating a string. You don't supply an encoding which is required.

Comment: Yes i know that but the problem is that i am fetching xml data from server from the link i mentioned in my question, the async request is failing by given that error message, now i don't understand when similar calls with exact same schema for the data i am fetching is working perfectly and this only one request to this particular url is failing.