# Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected in NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurlrequest, nsstringencoding

I am getting an error when i try to convert `NSData` to `NSString` in Swift

This is my request :

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 200)
```

I am getting the error here :

```
        var mydata :NSData = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)!.data
        var datastring = NSString(data: mydata, encoding: UInt()) as! String
```

My both try to get rid of the warning error but didn't work: 
i increased `timeoutInterval` to be 200 .

And i tried :

```
var myinfo = NSString(bytes: mydata.bytes, length: mydata.length, encoding: self.responseEncoding())

func responseEncoding() -> NSStringEncoding {

    return responseEncoding()


}
```

This solution didn't work for me here :
[Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317413/incorrect-nsstringencoding-value-0x0000-detected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UInt()` creates an integer with the value *zero*, so you are effectively
calling

```
var datastring = NSString(data: mydata, encoding: 0) as! String
```

But `0` is not a valid argument for the encoding parameter, you have to
replace it by a valid `NSStringEncoding`, e.g. `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Note also that the conversion can fail, so you better use optional
binding instead of a forced cast:

```
if let datastring = NSString(data: mydata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {

} else {
      // Encoding error ...
}
```